# How to Setup Symfony 1.4 on Mac 10.8.3 /Xampp/

Tags: symfony-1.4

Please someone explain how to install symfony 1.4 on Mac 10.8.3 with xampp. i am new on Mac and dont know anything. If u dont mind expain it step by step please. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Apache or any webserver (e.g. nginx, lighttpd...etc)
2. Install php (min 5.2.4)
3. Install MySQL
4. Read: http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet?orm=Doctrine

You should also consider using Symfony 2 instead if you're starting anew.

Comment: i already installed xampp so that mean i already got MySQL , Php , Apache.

Comment: Then it's a simple matter to read symfony's documention to get started. The link above is a full tutorial that guides you through making a simple site. Again, I encourage you to learn Symfony2 instead.

Comment: i read that tutorial before but i couldnt follow it as it said. So i decided to ask here..

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer you here... The tutorial is arguably one of the best tutorials written for any PHP framework. You can even not read anything and just run the commands and copy and paste in the code and it would work. I'm sorry but I can only assume you're being lazy and don't want to read.

Comment: first step to create project folder by $ mkdir -p /home/sfprojects/jobeet doenst work. It said command not fount o.O

Comment: i thought on mac 10.8.3 made some change. so i couldnt follow tutorial as it said. thats why i ask here. If i made you think so then sorry.

Comment: Operation not supported when i dont type $

Comment: Well this has now become non-symfony related. You should search for that error message you got for macs and go from there. I know you want people to answer your questions, but I hope you can also learn to try and solve problems by yourself too. SO should really be a last resort after at least 10min of googling.

Comment: To reassure modern-day readers who may alight here - the tutorial may have been "arguably one of the best tutorials written for any framework" when it was new, but it hasn't been updated and certainly doesn't cover MacOS. It is now legacy. One example - symfony-cli is now a standalone Go program, not a PHP script, so none of those examples work as written, although it's an easy step to convert them.